# How to convert dateTimes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, date, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT to parse Wordpress feed. But have a problem with some date format convert.
I need to pars  `<pubDate>Mon, 11 Oct 2021 13:23:10 +0000</pubDate>` to `2021-10-11T13:23:10z` . I have used

```
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">ds_date_created</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(pubDate,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
                </xsl:element>
```

xslt `format-date` function, but getting this message:

```
    Validation error at xsl:value-of on line 61 
      FORG0001: Invalid date "Mon, 01 Nov 2021 13:45:01 +000..." (Non-numeric year component)
     at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /rss/channel[1]/item[1]
```

Are this date can be converted by xslt? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it "manually", e.g. like this: https://gist.github.com/aendrew/eaa220e619008cbb628c

If you copy-paste the linked template definition, you can call it with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="format-from-rfc-to-iso">
    <xsl:with-param name="rfc-date" select="pubDate" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

instead of your `<xsl:value-of`

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 (e.g. Saxon 9.8 or later, Saxon-JS 2, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) you can use `parse-ietf-date` to parse that format, I think: `parse-ietf-date('Mon, 11 Oct 2021 13:23:10 +0000')`. That should give you an `xs:dateTime`, so for formatting it use `format-dateTime`.